# Alternatives for DOM API on Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, dom

We have an internal library that uses the org.w3c.dom DOM API to read and write XML. When attempting to use this library on Android I found that it no longer works. It appears that Android implements only a subset of the DOM API. I don't know the reasons for this, and I know that it's fixed in Android 2.2, but I still need to target older devices.

I know a number of alternative DOM libraries for "regular" Java, such as XOM and Dom4j. Can anyone recommend a DOM library that meets the following goals?

- It has to work on Android.
- It should be small (since people pay per MB).
- Ideally, it should be similar to the org.w3c.dom API since I need to rewrite the existing code.

It's probably impossible to meet all three goals, but with two I would already be happy. Also, out of curiosity, does anyone know *why* the DOM API is not fully supported? I can understand the reasons for not implementing Java Sound etc., but XML seems quite essential to me.

Comment: What parts of DOM are missing that you need? Does your library emit an error about an unimplemented or missing method?

Comment: Element.getTextContent(), Document.setXmlStandalone(), basically everything in the javax.xml.transform package (to write DOM objects back to files).

Answer (score 1):

My general recommendation would be to stay well away from a DOM parser, because the performance is abysmal compared to using a direct parser.  You would be much better off parsing with XmlPullParser or SAX.

I know, you already have code that uses DOM, and that is how you want to do it.  But believe me, you should not be using this on a mobile device.

Comment: That's interesting input. Do you have benchmarks / studies to back up your claim?

Comment: When I looked many years ago, it was about a factor of 10x slower.  Basically you get an order of magnitude (or more) slower as you move from parsing with Resources().getXml(), to XmlPullParser/SAX, to DOM.

Comment: Things have changed a lot in the XML world with improved Xerces/Xalan and JVM's, even with improved garbage collection algorithms. I feel DOM is very fast today, and very suitable for most use cases (not necessarily on Android, though). Unfortunately, I can't back that up with facts either...

Comment: We're talking about Android though.  You are welcome to do some performance tests, I freely admit that it has been a few years since I did mine.  Currently I strongly recommend people avoid it.  If nothing else, just having to load the entire XML file into RAM as a parsed structure is not too desirable for a mobile device.